# How do you check if the client for a MongoDB instance is valid?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In particular, I am currently trying to check if a connection to a client is valid using the following function:

```
def mongodb_connect(client_uri):
    try:
        return pymongo.MongoClient(client_uri)
    except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure:
         print "Failed to connect to server {}".format(client_uri)
```

I then use this function like this:

```
def bucket_summary(self):
    client_uri = "some_client_uri"
    client = mongodb_connect(client_uri)
    db = client[tenant_id]
    ttb = db.timebucket.count() # If I use an invalid URI it hangs here
```

Is there a way to catch and throw an exception at the last line if an invalid URI is given? I initially thought that's what the ConnectionFailure was for (so this could be caught when connecting) but I was wrong.

If I run the program with an invalid URI, which fails to run, issuing a KeyboardInterrupt yields:

```
File "reportjob_status.py", line 58, in <module>
tester.summarize_timebuckets()
File "reportjob_status.py", line 43, in summarize_timebuckets
ttb = db.timebucket.count() #error
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line   1023, in count
return self._count(cmd)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 985, in _count
with self._socket_for_reads() as (sock_info, slave_ok):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 699, in _socket_for_reads
with self._get_socket(read_preference) as sock_info:
File  "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 663, in _get_socket
server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 121, in select_server
address))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 106, in select_servers
self._condition.wait(common.MIN_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 358, in wait
_sleep(delay)
```

Comment: pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure is thrown when the host from client_uri is not available but if the database doesn't exist at host it's created, so you have to ckeck the existence of the db before.

Comment: Thanks. How do you check the existence of the db beforehand though?

Comment: The method database_names in MongoClient class could help.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The `serverSelectionTimeoutMS` keyword parameter of [`pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient) controls how long the driver will try to connect to a server. The default value is 30s.

Set it to a very low value compatible with your typical connection time¹ to immediately report an error. You need to query the DB after that to trigger a connection attempt :

```
>>> maxSevSelDelay = 1 # Assume 1ms maximum server selection delay
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient("someInvalidURIOrNonExistantHost",
                                 serverSelectionTimeoutMS=maxSevSelDelay)
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>>> client.server_info()
```

This will raise [`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError).

<sub>¹ *Apparently* setting `serverSelectionTimeoutMS` to `0` might even work in the particular case your server has very low latency (case of a "local" server with very light load for example)</sub>

---

It is up to you to catch that exception and to handle it properly. Something *like* that:

```
try:
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("someInvalidURIOrNonExistantHost",
                                     serverSelectionTimeoutMS=maxSevSelDelay)
    client.server_info() # force connection on a request as the
                         # connect=True parameter of MongoClient seems
                         # to be useless here 
except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError as err:
    # do whatever you need
    print(err)
```

will display:

```
No servers found yet
```

Comment: This works well. I had an issue where if the serverSelectionTimeoutMS was set to 0 it would always say the MongoDB instance was down. Setting it to 1 ms fixed this issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @James ! I've updated the answer accordingly. Are you running a *cluster* of MongoDB servers  or a *single* server ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I'm just using a single server :)

Comment: I think that now you can use [`pymongo.MongoClient.is_mongos`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.is_mongos) to do the same thing nowadays.

Answer (score 27):

Hi to find out that the connection is established or not you can do that :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
client = MongoClient()
try:
   # The ismaster command is cheap and does not require auth.
   client.admin.command('ismaster')
except ConnectionFailure:
   print("Server not available")
```

Comment: Upvoted and should be the accepted answer, because this is what is [advertised in the comments of the MongoClient class](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/c8d920a46bfb7b054326b3e983943bfc794cb676/pymongo/mongo_client.py#L157-L173).

Answer (score 4):

**serverSelectionTimeoutMS**

> This defines how long to block for server selection before throwing an
>   exception. The default is 30,000 (milliseconds). It MUST be
>   configurable at the client level. It MUST NOT be configurable at the
>   level of a database object, collection object, or at the level of an
>   individual query.
>
> This default value was chosen to be sufficient for a typical server
>   primary election to complete. As the server improves the speed of
>   elections, this number may be revised downward.
>
> Users that can tolerate long delays for server selection when the
>   topology is in flux can set this higher. Users that want to "fail
>   fast" when the topology is in flux can set this to a small number.
>
> A serverSelectionTimeoutMS of zero MAY have special meaning in some
>   drivers; zero's meaning is not defined in this spec, but all drivers
>   SHOULD document the meaning of zero.

https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-selection/server-selection.rst#serverselectiontimeoutms

```
# pymongo 3.5.1
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import ServerSelectionTimeoutError

client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27000/", serverSelectionTimeoutMS=10, connectTimeoutMS=20000)

try:
    info = client.server_info() # Forces a call.
except ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
    print("server is down.")

# If connection create a new one with serverSelectionTimeoutMS=30000
```

Answer (score 2):

`serverSelectionTimeoutMS` doesn't work for me (Python 2.7.12, MongoDB 3.6.1, pymongo 3.6.0).  [A. Jesse Jiryu Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618967/a-jesse-jiryu-davis) suggested in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/issues/87#issuecomment-222285974) that we attempt a socket-level connection first as a litmus test.  This does the trick for me.

```
def throw_if_mongodb_is_unavailable(host, port):
    import socket
    sock = None
    try:
        sock = socket.create_connection(
            (host, port),
            timeout=1) # one second
    except socket.error as err:
        raise EnvironmentError(
            "Can't connect to MongoDB at {host}:{port} because: {err}"
            .format(**locals()))
    finally:
        if sock is not None:
            sock.close()

# elsewhere...
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 27017
throw_if_mongodb_is_unavailable(HOST, PORT)
import pymongo
conn = pymongo.MongoClient(HOST, PORT)
print(conn.admin.command('ismaster'))
# etc.
```

There are plenty of problems this won't catch, but if the server isn't running or isn't reachable, this'll show you right away.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be checked this way:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import OperationFailure

def check_mongo_connection(client_uri):
    connection = MongoClient(client_uri)

    try:
        connection.database_names()
        print('Data Base Connection Established........')

    except OperationFailure as err:
        print(f"Data Base Connection failed. Error: {err}")

check_mongo_connection(client_uri)
```

Answer (score 0):

For **pymongo >= 4.0** the preferred method is to use `ping` command [instead of deprecated `ismaster`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-2848):

```py
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
client = MongoClient()

try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
except ConnectionFailure:
    print("Server not available")
```

To handle auth failures, include `OperationFailure`:

```py
except OperationFailure as err:
    print(f"Database error encountered: {err}")
```

Source: [mongo_client.py](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3204290e93594f8ffe537ca5e7ed071d4c13056e/pymongo/mongo_client.py#L212)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def mongo_available():
    maxsevseldelay = 1  # Assume 1ms maximum server selection delay
    client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost2:27017',serverSelectionTimeoutMS=maxsevseldelay)
    try:
        # The ping command is cheap and does not require auth.
        client.admin.command('ping')
        return True, "Mongo connection working fine"
    except ConnectionFailure:
        return False, "Mongo Server not available"
        

mongo_available()
(False, 'Mongo Server not available')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your code?

Answer (score 0):

This will loop for 30 seconds trying to ping to your deployment. Worked well for me.

```
# Connect to Mongo client
client = MongoClient(mongo_connection_string)

# Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
end_time = time.time() + 30
while time.time() < end_time:
    try:
        client.admin.command('ping')
        print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
        break  # Successful connection, exit the loop
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to connect: {e}")
```

Comment: I would not advise catching a general exception because it may introduce side effects.