# how to reconnect mongdb in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm using mongoengine to connect mongodb in python, when the network fails, I need to reconnect mongodb so that I can continue update data, how am I suppose to do that?
Here's my code

```
import mongoengine
conn = mongoengine.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=27017)
# how to reconnect mongodb?
```

Comment: by default, pymongo enables autoreconnect.

Comment: Thank you! I'm now using autoreconnect by modifying serverSelectionTimeoutMS and socketTimeoutMS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check if the client for a MongoDB instance is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539183/how-do-you-check-if-the-client-for-a-mongodb-instance-is-valid)